# Start Jenkins jobs by scheduler and push events

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've configured a [declarative](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline) and [multibranch](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/) pipeline in Jenkins. This job is started when there is a push event in its git repository. Meaning that every time somebody pushes into a branch, Jenkins runs the job to build that branch.

Now, however, only the master branch has to be started by push events and the other branches will be scheduled to be built every night. To do so, I've added the following in my Jenkinsfile:

```
String cronSchedule = BRANCH_NAME != "master" ? "0 0 * * *" : ""

triggers {
  cron(cronSchedule)
}
```

This works fine, the branches different to master are built every night.

However, when I push into any branch (i.e. feature/demo-branch) the job is started as well. I expected that the branches which are scheduled would be started only at night and not when I do a `git push`.

I've seen there is an option to ignore the push events:

[image: Ignore push event option]

But I haven't seen an option to enable this only for certain branches.

Is there some way to configure multibranch job where some branches are started only by push events and other branches are started only by a cron schedule?